# Python regex issue -- [\S\s]* vs \d*

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find and replace a certain string in Python 2.7. Here is my string (shown raw):

`\n\n\nTOSS UP\n\n\n\n1. MATH  Short Answer  Pablo walks 4 miles north, 6 miles east, and then 2 miles north again. In simplest form, how many miles is he from his starting point?\n\n\n\nANSWER: 6\n\n\n\nBONUS\n\n\n\n1. MATH  Short Answer  Evaluate the limit as x approaches infinity of x times the quantity negative 1 plus e to the 1 over x.\n\n\n\nANSWER: 1\n\n\n\nTOSS UP\n\n\n\n2. CHEMISTRY  Multiple Choice  Which of the following is NOT a characteristic of amines?\n\n\n\nW) A fully protonated amine is called an ammonium ion\n\nX) Amines can function as Br\xc3\xb8nsted bases\n\nY) The VSEPR geometry of the nitrogen atom is trigonal planar\n\nZ) Amines can be a hydrogen bond acceptor\n\n\n\nANSWER: Y) The VSEPR geometry of the nitrogen atom is trigonal planar\n\n\n\nBONUS\n\n\n\n2. CHEMISTRY  Multiple Choice  Of the following elements in their monatomic gaseous states, which has the lowest electron affinity?\n\n\n\nW) BoronX) CarbonY) NitrogenZ) OxygenANSWER: Y) NITROGEN\n\n\n`

I'm using this regex to search it, and then doing a few replacements:

```
searchString = (
    r"(TOSS\-UP|TOSSUP|TOSS\s*UP)\s*"
    r"(?P<questionNum>\d{1,2})[\.\)]\s*(?P<category>[A-Z ]+)\s*"
    r"(?i)(Short Answer|Multiple Choice)\s*(?P<tossupQ>[\S\s]*)"
    r"ANSWER\:\s*(?P<tossupA>[\S\s]*)"

    r"\s*BONUS\s*"
    r"(?P<questionNumBonus>\d{1,2})[\.\)]\s*(?P<categoryBonus>[A-Z ]+)\s*"
    r"(?i)(Short Answer|Multiple Choice)\s*(?P<bonusQ>[\S\s]*)"
    r"ANSWER\:(?P<bonusA>[\S\s]*)"
)
```

The result I get is this:

```
{
    "category": 4,
    "questionNum": 1,
    "tossupQ": "Pablo walks 4 miles north, 6 miles east, and then 2 miles north again. In simplest form, how many miles is he from his starting point?\n\n\n\nANSWER: 6\n\n\n\nBONUS\n\n\n\n1. MATH  Short Answer  Evaluate the limit as x approaches infinity of x times the quantity negative 1 plus e to the 1 over x.\n\n\n\nANSWER: 1\n\n\n\nTOSS UP\n\n\n\n2. CHEMISTRY  Multiple Choice  Which of the following is NOT a characteristic of amines?\n\n\n\nW) A fully protonated amine is called an ammonium ion\n\nX) Amines can function as Br\xc3\xb8nsted bases\n\nY) The VSEPR geometry of the nitrogen atom is trigonal planar\n\nZ) Amines can be a hydrogen bond acceptor",
    "tossupA": "Y) The VSEPR geometry of the nitrogen atom is trigonal planar",
    "bonusQ": "Of the following elements in their monatomic gaseous states, which has the lowest electron affinity?\n\n\n\nW) BoronX) CarbonY) NitrogenZ) Oxygen",
    "bonusA": "Y) NITROGEN"
},
```

However, when I change the line `r"ANSWER\:\s*(?P<tossupA>[\S\s]*)"` to `r"ANSWER\:\s*(?P<tossupA>[\d]*)"`, I get this:

```
{
    "category": 4,
    "questionNum": 1,
    "tossupQ": "Pablo walks 4 miles north, 6 miles east, and then 2 miles north again. In simplest form, how many miles is he from his starting point?",
    "tossupA": "6",
    "bonusQ": "Evaluate the limit as x approaches infinity of x times the quantity negative 1 plus e to the 1 over x.\n\n\n\nANSWER: 1\n\n\n\nTOSS UP\n\n\n\n2. CHEMISTRY  Multiple Choice  Which of the following is NOT a characteristic of amines?\n\n\n\nW) A fully protonated amine is called an ammonium ion\n\nX) Amines can function as Br\xc3\xb8nsted bases\n\nY) The VSEPR geometry of the nitrogen atom is trigonal planar\n\nZ) Amines can be a hydrogen bond acceptor\n\n\n\nANSWER: Y) The VSEPR geometry of the nitrogen atom is trigonal planar\n\n\n\nBONUS\n\n\n\n2. CHEMISTRY  Multiple Choice  Of the following elements in their monatomic gaseous states, which has the lowest electron affinity?\n\n\n\nW) BoronX) CarbonY) NitrogenZ) Oxygen",
    "bonusA": "Y) NITROGEN"
},
```

**Why** does tossupA not match to [\S\s]* , but does match only to \d*? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you isolate the particular regex expression and test string that is causing you problems? Also what were you expecting 'tossupA' to be in your example?

Comment: The ones I posted above were the isolated ones. I expect "tossupA" to be "6", but I am just confused as to why it does not match to [\S\s]* , while it _does_ match only to \d*

Comment: `[\S\s]*` matches anything, `[\d]*` just matches digits. Why would you expect the first one to only match digits?

Comment: @Barmar the expression is followed by BONUS though, so it should only match all characters up to "BONUS" -- which is "6\n\n\n\n"

Comment: The '6' seems to have been captured by 'tossupQ', if you use `[\S\s]*` (equivalent to `.*`), you are saying just match any character, so the previous capture goes all the way to the last 'ANSWER: Y) The VSEPR...' (since this satisfies `.*`), in this case, it skips to the first multiple choice, with answer Y). When you use `\d*`, there are no other numerical answers that are also followed by a 'BONUS' except for the first so it matches '6'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you're using greedy quantifiers. When you don't restrict `Answer:` to be followed by digits, it allows `tossupQ` to match a a longer string. As a result, `tossupQ` contains all the questions and answers until the last `Answer:`.

When you require `Answer:` to be followed by digits, `tossupA` can only match the first answer, and `tossupQ` has to stop earlier to allow this match.

You can solve this by changing to non-greedy quantifiers: `*?`. This will cause them to match the shortest strings consistent with the rest of the pattern, rather than the longest one.

```
searchString = (
    r"(TOSS\-UP|TOSSUP|TOSS\s*UP)\s*"
    r"(?P<questionNum>\d{1,2})[\.\)]\s*(?P<category>[A-Z ]+)\s*"
    r"(?i)(Short Answer|Multiple Choice)\s*(?P<tossupQ>[\S\s]*?)"
    r"ANSWER\:\s*(?P<tossupA>[\S\s]*?)"

    r"\s*BONUS\s*"
    r"(?P<questionNumBonus>\d{1,2})[\.\)]\s*(?P<categoryBonus>[A-Z ]+)\s*"
    r"(?i)(Short Answer|Multiple Choice)\s*(?P<bonusQ>[\S\s]*?)"
    r"ANSWER\:(?P<bonusA>[\S\s]*)"
)
```

BTW, `[\S\s]` is the same as `.`. If you want the match to span multiple lines, use the `re.DOTALL` flag to allow it to match newlines.

Comment: Because there's nothing restricting `bonusA` to a specific answer, so again the greedy regexp goes as far as it can.

Comment: @eugenhu That's why I added the `?` in both `tossupQ` and `bonusQ`.

Comment: Yeah commented that before the edit just to clarify there are more issues with the search string than just `\d*`, uh guess I'll delete these comments now.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that -- however, because it's non-greedy, now it's not matching anything for "bonusA" because it's at the end of the search string. How do you suggest I fix this?

Comment: Yeah, shouldn't use non-greedy at the end.